# Github PAT on deployment

Tags: reactjs, github-actions, github-pages

I have a project where I need to use a Github personal access token to hit the GitHub API endpoint. My project is only frontend using React and I deployed using GH-pages. So I believe my problem is in my YAML file, where I create a .env file during build and push the environment variable I set on Github secrets/environment settings. During the CI/CD process, my token gets revoked because it's a PAT, but I made it "scopeless" so it shouldn't be revoked according to the documentation.

`OAuth tokens and personal access tokens pushed to public repositories and public gists will only be revoked if the token has scopes.`

Have I mistaken something here? I am trying to understand what's going on. So what I think is happening is that this new .env file is being deployed with the project, and I assumed that after the job is complete, it's wiped, but clearly that's not what's happening as the cause for the token being revoked is that it appeared somewhere in my script. It is not.

```
    - run: |
          cd ./frontend
          touch .env
          echo 'REACT_APP_GHTOKEN : ${{ env.REACT_APP_GHTOKEN }}' >> .env
          npm install
          npm run build
```

Any advice?

Comment: `as the cause for the token being revoked is that it appeared somewhere in my script. It is not.` -  I have a hard time understanding this part. You have to know that any env variable that you build text project with is present in the output js files as plain text and everyone can read it

Comment: I am guessing that somewhere in my build bundle contains a reference to the key in the .env that i'd have to change. I wanted to see if I would be able to find it hard coded in the build but i couldn't and was stuck on where I can go around this issue. I do know the .env file will be visible but I am not understanding why its being revoked under these circumstances.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use [GitHub Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets), and not to check your PAT into version control. Also Actions can use the default [`GITHUB_TOKEN` secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) without any setup if you just need access to the current repo.

Comment: I have both an environment secret and a repository secret set up as my PAT bearer token, thats how i'm accessing it using env.react_app_bearer. I have been trying different ways to get process.env to work for this key but it just gets revoked. I'm not aware of another way to get process.env to get the react_app_var without building a .env file with Github actions. If anyone has another way, i'm all ears.

Comment: you can try writing it to github env as :: code ::

echo REACT_APP_GHTOKEN="${{ env.REACT_APP_GHTOKEN }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV

Comment: Is process.env supposed to be able to recognize $GITHUB_ENV as it's environment?